# Problem dealing with creation and annihilation operators of two uncoupled oscillators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, harmonic-oscillator, open-quantum-systems

I encountered a expression of the form while computing the Lindbladian of two uncoupled harmonic oscillators
$$2 b^{\dagger}a a^{\dagger}a^{\dagger}b-a^{\dagger}a^{\dagger}b b^{\dagger}a-a^{\dagger}b b^{\dagger}a a^{\dagger}$$

Note that $[a,a^{\dagger}]=1$ , $[b,b^{\dagger}]=1$ and any commutator between $a,b$ and their conjugates are zero.

What is the answer to this and is there any technique to compute such expressions fast.

Comment: "What is the answer" to what?  It's not clear there is a question here...

Comment: @ZeroTheHero my question is how to simplify the above expression to product of a , b or their conjugates

Comment: just use the commutation relations you have given...

Answer (score 2):

Recast your expression to
$$
2N_b(N_a+1) a^\dagger -a^\dagger N_a (N_b +1) - a^\dagger (N_b+1) (N_a+1)\\
=a^\dagger (2N_b(N_a+2)-…).
$$
Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thank you so much Prof Cosmas !